# use WorksheetFunction with ctrl shift enter in VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a VBA code to find matching cell based on given value without considering Text and Number.

We can do it in Excel like this: `=match("*207*", C:C & "",0)` with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

But in VBA the code `pos = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_range & "", 0)` doesn't work.
Is there any solution?

Comment: Is `pos` a Range? If so, try `pos.FormulaArray = WorksheetFunction.Match(lookup_value, lookup_range & "", 0) `.

Comment: Look into worksheet.evaluate. It will do array formulas.

Comment: `pos` cannot be Range. It's as a Variant type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lookup_range & ""` wont work in VBA, because you cannot concatenate a `String` to a `Range` object nor to an `Array`. Use `Evaluate` instead:

```
pos=Sheet1.Evaluate("match(""*207*"", C:C & """",0)")
```

---

To use the variables in the evaluation, this:

```
pos = Application.Evaluate("MATCH(""*" & lookup_value & "*""," & _
  lookup_range.Address(External:=True) & "& """",0)")
```

Comment: In VBA, I want to use variables lookup_value, lookup_range. I use this code in UDF.

Comment: @AliM67 - Then just "break up" the formula to allow those to be used, no?

Comment: @BruceWayne - Please, explain more. Do you mean this way: `pos = Application.Evaluate("Match(" & lookup_value & ", " & lookup_range & " & "", 0)")`

Comment: @AliM67 see the last (added) part.

Comment: @BruceWayne thanks for help, I think it should be `lookup_range.Address` there, plus some escapes for the quotes.

Comment: @A.S.H - Thank you. It works fine. I changed it to below to work with all possible user inputs: `Application.Evaluate("MATCH(""" & CStr(lookup_value) & """," & lookup_range.Address(External:=True) & "& """",0)")`

Comment: @AliM67 That's perfect. Glad to help.